# cleaning up multiple jquery functions

Tags: jquery

I have 12 functions all doing the same job but simply targeting different elements. I am trying to clean up my code and see if there is way to create one single function for it.

example:

```
    function incrementValue()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}
function incrementValue2()
{
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number2').value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number2').value = value;
}
```

Basically each time the button is clicked it increments the value inside the input.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="VOTE" />
<a href="option1.html" title="More information"><img src="icon.png" /></a>
```

I have tried but always seems to be something breaking :/ Not sure what I am doing wrong. Can't seem to find clear tutorials on this, so if someone could maybe just point me towards a tutorial I can then work out the code and answer this myself!

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the HTML

Comment: HTML added, sorry about that!

Comment: You are declaring 'value' twice. I am not sure you can do that.

Comment: Does it increment all the fields on one button click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need a parametrized function:

```
function incrementValue( target )
{
    var el = document.getElementById( target );
    var value = parseInt( el.value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    el.value = value;
}
```

Then you can call this function with

```
incrementValue( 'number' );
incrementValue( 'number2' );
// etc.
```

Comment: I have just tried this and it works on the first click but then does not add any more, just stops working at (1)

Comment: Here is the code supplied by yourself
http://jsfiddle.net/w488Q/

As you can see it changes to (1) but then stops

Comment: @DamianSmith There was a typo in my code (switched `el` and `target`). With that being fixed, it works as can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w488Q/1/).

Comment: 'function incrementValue( target )
{
    var el = document.getElementById( target );
    var value = parseInt( el.value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    el.value = value;
}'

Comment: yes, i just spotted it myself!

Thank you so much for that, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** to handle this case

```
$("input[id^=number]")
```